# How to inlude orcid for lni class?

Tags: hyperref, templates

I'm not sure how to add orcid for [Lni style](https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI/blob/main/lni.cls).

`\usepackage{orcidlink}` results in `Option clash for package hyperref. \begin{document}`

Defining

```
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}
```

results in a bunch of `Undefined control sequence` all over the doc.

Did anyone manage to include it?

Comment: Did you try to put the `\usepackage` top most or even `\RequirePackage{orcidlink}` before the `\documentclass`?

Comment: yes, no success. Still complains about clash for package hyperref. I don't include it, so it's probably somewhere inside the lni class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orcidlink` loads package `hyperref` without option, but `lni` wants to load `hyperref` with option `bookmarks=false` via `\AtEndPreamble`, after it has been loaded by `orcidlink` (without option). This fails. Unfortunately adding `bookmarks=false` to the global options (aka optional argument of `\documentclass`) does not help in this case. But using `\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}` before `\documentclass` does work:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass{lni}

\usepackage{orcidlink}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Using `\AtEndPreamble` to load `orcidlink` would also work, because in this case it is loaded after `hyperref` (from within `lni`) and loading a package without option, that already has been loaded with option, is valid.

```latex
\documentclass{lni}

\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{orcidlink}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

See the `etoolbox` manual for more information about `\AtEndPreamble`.

Please note: This answer does not constitute an opinion as to the acceptability by the GI of documents prepared using any of the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly